# Is it possible to dynamically declare a java pojo class from xml configuration file?

Tags: java, xml

Is it possible to dynamically declare java pojo bean classes from an xml config file?

Say if the config file is like - A.xml:

```
   <xml>
    <memberValues>
    <memberValue>
    <dataType>String</dataType>
    <name>productName</name>
    <value>Hello World!</value>
    </memberValue>
    <memberValue>
    <dataType>Double</dataType>
    <name>productPrice</name>
    <value>31.99</value>
    </memberValue>
    ...
    <memberValues>
    </xml>
```

It should declare a new java pojo bean class on the fly like - A.java:

```
   public class A{
    private String productName = "Hello World!";
    private Double productPrice = 31.99;

    //getters and setters
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Why? What's the problem you're trying to solve? Why can't you use a proper Java class declaration?

Comment: Yes, possible.You can use Java reflection API to do so.

Comment: I am trying to create a product simulator in which users can add new products on the fly by specifying the product configuration.

Comment: when you want to compile the souce, at the same runtime?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to generate Java source code and invoke the JavaCompiler class. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty close to what I was looking for:
http://blog.javaforge.net/post/31913732423/howto-create-java-pojo-at-runtime-with-javassist

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using JAXB java APIs,

if your xml is like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>  
<employee id="1">  
    <name>User</name>  
    <salary>50000.0</salary>  
</employee>
```

then you can use following java code for converting xml file to java object

```
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Employee.class);    

    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();    
    Employee e=(Employee) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

for more information you can see the [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-tutorial)

Comment: for this you would need to have Employee class declared in advance no? I need a solution in which this can be done on fly based on configuration in xml file.

Comment: Yes for this you need to create xml file with Employee class, Is your xml schema is constant ?